# New to assembly, is there such thing as "generic assembly code"?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I'm new to assembly (much more used to working with C#), but I've decided to see if I can learn it and get more of an idea of what my computer does under the hood.

My question is, when programming on Windows, do I have to use the win32 libraries? For example, if I want to output, say, "A" in a console window, is there a "generic" way to do it, or do I have to call win32? Or am I completely off on how it works?

Comment: What do you mean by ".code"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - if I'm not mistaken, it starts the code section of an assembly program - see for example this tutorial http://www.infernodevelopment.com/introduction-masm32 under ".data" ".model" and stuff there's a ".code" section

Comment: A quick Google search on "assembly language tutorial" turned up dozens of links. As you've indicated you already know, this site is not for "teach me how to program" or "find me a tutorial" types of questions. Voting to close as not constructive. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more info on the types of questions that should be asked here - the general rule is "a specific programming problem".

Comment: I see what you're saying about some examples. Some examples will simply omit the obvious, expecting you to know it by then.

Comment: @KenWhite OK, just thought I'd try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Win32 unless you need something that Win32 does. I don't believe there is any level more primitive than Win32 for doing things like outputting to the console, for instance.